# Using special characters of a font

Tags: fonts, photoshop

I'm using this font https://www.1001fonts.com/thanks-valentine-personal-use-font.html called "Thanks Valentine".

In the demo it's showing how the TITLING and LIGATURE works:
[image: font demo]

I tried a few things, but still I do not know how to trigger these "features" of the font. For example, I want to see the special titling T with the heart and not the regular T, yet no matter what I do I get only the regular T.

Comment: Have you looped through all characters with css & javascript?

Comment: @ghoul No I did not, thanks good idea :)

Comment: In MS Word selecting the font and going to `Insert -> Symbol`. Will show the whole character map, someties clicking on a side to select a `Subset` can narrow the selection and you should be able to invoke hard to reach character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the photoshop side the glyphs can be displayed by clicking the `Glyphs` button and then selecting the specific subset of the font:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows bundled character map shows too many (multilingual) characters and it's hard to find it in the haystack. Displaying all characters of a font with CSS/Javascript just to find out which character to use could work, but looks like an overhead when there is a shorter approach.

The font website has already a feature to list all characters:

[image]